# Is it possible to add arguments for user defined passes in llvm

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api, llvm-ir

Now we are implementing a analysis pass for **llvm**, following [this tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html). and need to pass an additional argument to the plugin such as below:

```
opt -load /path/to/myplugin.so -mypass -mypass_option input.bc
```

However I did not find any manual telling me how to do. So I'm wondering whether it is possible in practice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That particular example is not optimal because the idiom is to read from `stdin`.  Presumably you have another use case in mind?

Comment: What kind of argument do you need? As far as I know a pass should take everything it needs from the IR and output IR again.

Comment: @TobiasLangner It's some argument like the analysis level or analysis location of the `-mypass` pass. Maybe it is like the gcc optimization level `-O1`,`-O2`,etc.

Comment: @BrianCain I was considering to read the `mypass_option` from a file, however it seems that I have to modify the specified file every time I use the pass.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use the [CommandLine](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandLine.html) library which comes built-in with LLVM. Basically, you just put at the top of the .cpp file of the pass:

```
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"

static cl::opt<string> InputFilename("mypass_option", cl::desc("Specify input filename for mypass"), cl::value_desc("filename"));
```

But I recommend you check the above link, it has full reference + convenient quickstart section.

For an example, take a look at the built-in [loop unrolling pass](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/LoopUnrollPass_8cpp_source.html) - it defines two unsigned and two boolean options, right at the top of the source file, by using `cl::opt<unsigned>` and `cl::opt<bool>`.

Comment: How to get the value form the argument ?

Comment: just access InputFilename